# Spring Security SAML SSO redirect to controller

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Using fragment of the code to redirect to the controller (/bootstrap/v1) in IdP-initiated setup:

```
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/bootstrap/v1");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}
```

Controller code fragment:

```
public class BootstrapController extends ParentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BootstrapResponseDto> bootstrap(@RequestBody BootstrapRequestDto bootstrapRequestDto, @RequestHeader(value = "MAC-ADDRESS", required = false) String macAddress) {

        myAppUserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextUtils.getUserDetails();

        BootstrapResponseDto bootstrapResponseDto = new BootstrapResponseDto();

        // some app specific logic goes here...

        return new ResponseEntity<>(bootstrapResponseDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Debug level log fragment:

> 11-29-2018 13:33:53 e7a5edb2-4051-4132-bad0-856d58af1c7d
>   ZDJhMWExYWUtZTAxNy00NDQwLWJmOTctNzcyNTJlOWUyNmQ2   INFO
>   http-nio-8080-exec-6 Spring Security Debugger:
>
> ---
>
> Request received for POST '/saml/SSO':
>
> org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@28cc5b21
>
> servletPath:/saml/SSO pathInfo:null headers:  host: localhost:8080
>   user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:63.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0 accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5 accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
>   content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-length: 11320
>   dnt: 1 connection: keep-alive cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=ZDJhMWExYWUtZTAxNy00NDQwLWJmOTctNzcyNTJlOWUyNmQ2
>   upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
>
> Security filter chain: [   MetadataGeneratorFilter
>   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   CustomLogFilter   HeaderWriterFilter   LogoutFilter
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter   BasicAuthenticationFilter
>   FilterChainProxy   RequestCacheAwareFilter
>   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter   SessionManagementFilter
>   ExceptionTranslationFilter   FilterSecurityInterceptor ]
>
> ---
>
> 11-29-2018 13:33:53 e7a5edb2-4051-4132-bad0-856d58af1c7d    INFO
>   http-nio-8080-exec-6
>   o.o.c.b.s.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:
>   Validation of protocol message signature succeeded, message type:
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response 11-29-2018 13:33:53 e7a5edb2-4051-4132-bad0-856d58af1c7d
>   ZDJhMWExYWUtZTAxNy00NDQwLWJmOTctNzcyNTJlOWUyNmQ2   INFO
>   http-nio-8080-exec-7 Spring Security Debugger:
>
> ---
>
> Request received for GET '/bootstrap/v1':
>
> org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@5f9e2aff
>
> servletPath:/bootstrap/v1 pathInfo:null headers:  host: localhost:8080
>   user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:63.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0 accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5 accept-encoding: gzip, deflate dnt: 1
>   connection: keep-alive cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=ZDJhMWExYWUtZTAxNy00NDQwLWJmOTctNzcyNTJlOWUyNmQ2
>   upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
>
> Security filter chain: [   MetadataGeneratorFilter
>   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   CustomLogFilter   HeaderWriterFilter   LogoutFilter
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter   BasicAuthenticationFilter
>   FilterChainProxy   RequestCacheAwareFilter
>   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter   SessionManagementFilter
>   ExceptionTranslationFilter   FilterSecurityInterceptor ]
>
> ---
>
> 11-29-2018 13:33:53 e7a5edb2-4051-4132-bad0-856d58af1c7d    WARN
>   http-nio-8080-exec-7 o.s.w.s.PageNotFound: Request method 'GET' not
>   supported

ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken set to return:

> org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@fee70636: Principal: com.<my-company>.security.authentication.@325fcf8b; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: authority_1, authority_2, authority_3, authority_4

So, I'm guessing my SAML validation and user authentication & authorization is good.

Seem like the issue I'm facing is that HTTP GET ins't going to work.

How to configure and submit HTTP POST instead? or
Should I refactor my controller to handle behavior (which could break form-based login that also part of the app's authentication)?

[HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkOR2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is not at all related to SAML, but a generic Spring Security question. Also, you don't specify where the body, BootstrapRequestDto, comes from.

You have a SuccessHandler, that does a redirect:

`successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/bootstrap/v1");`
This performs a `GET`

And you have a controller only accepts `POST`. And you haven't specified where that body comes from?

You will need to write a custom success handler that issues a post(javascript auto submit form maybe?), or just change your controller to also accept GET.

```
public class BootstrapController extends ParentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BootstrapResponseDto> bootstrap() {

        myAppUserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextUtils.getUserDetails();
        BootstrapResponseDto bootstrapResponseDto = new bootstrapResponseDto();

        // some app specific logic goes here...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bootstrapResponseDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BootstrapResponseDto> bootstrap(@RequestBody BootstrapRequestDto bootstrapRequestDto, @RequestHeader(value = "MAC-ADDRESS", required = false) String macAddress) {

        myAppUserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextUtils.getUserDetails();

        BootstrapResponseDto bootstrapResponseDto = new BootstrapResponseDto();

        // some app specific logic goes here...

        return new ResponseEntity<>(bootstrapResponseDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... I was thinking along those lines (implementing GET method on the controller) and you have confirmed that would be way to go about this.

Comment: Hey, works like a charm.

Seem like I still need to redirect back to JavaScript controller on the frontend to do some more processing for UI rendering; at this point response posted back to a browser as a naked json. Ideas how would one go about doing this?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8")

Comment: @SBatCCOC Please upvote my answer if you find it useful.